# Linking Textboxes C# SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server

How do I link textboxes?

Scenario:

```
TextBox_Supplier
TextBox_Address
```

`TextBox_Supplier` is autocomplete and it's working. When typing is done in `TextBox_Supplier`, the `TextBox_Address` will select supplier's address.

My code does not work:

```
private void txb_vendor_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txb_address.Text))
    {
        PurCon.con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = PurCon.getcon();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = String.Format("SELECT address FROM tbl_Supplier WHERE supplier_name = {0}",txb_vendor.Text);

        SqlDataReader red = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (red.Read())
        {
            string address = red.GetString(0);
            address = txb_address.Text;
        }

        PurCon.con.Close();
    }
}
```

Thank you for helping me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already solved this problem last week. And I'm so angry to myself!

The textbox_Address does not changed once, it stacks up when the `textbox_Supplier_TextChaged`. So I put Clear() method to clear previous input address.

```
public void AddressTbxLoad()
    {

        DBCon PurCon = new DBCon();
        PurCon.con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = PurCon2.con;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = String.Format("SELECT address FROM tbl_Supplier WHERE supplier_name LIKE '{0}%'", cbx_vendor.Text);
        SqlDataReader red = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (red.Read())
        {
            string address = red.GetString(0);
            txb_address.Text = address;

        }
        PurCon.con.Close();
    }

    private void cbx_vendor_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txb_address.Clear();
        AddressTbxLoad();
    }

    private void Purchase_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        VendorTbxLoad();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

instead of

```
address = txb_address.Text;
```

write

```
txb_address.Text = address;
```

Try to use Parameterized Query instead of concatenation of the strings.

Comment: Sir! @mohit-shrivastava the code works. But the TextBox_Address only text changed once. Like when I type one char, it gives me a random address that related to the char I typed. I want to have a synchronize textbox that when typing the address always change until the TextBox_Vendor is complete. I do this in VB.Net but I can't do in C#

Comment: Try to do that in `LostFocus` event instead of `TextChanged`. That would populate the address only after you left the textbox. That would also save your database call on every keypress.

Comment: Sir! @mohit-shrivastava I don't see `LostFocus` event instead I saw `Leave` event. Is that what you saying?

I try the `Leave` event. At first it worked but when I try to change the supplier_name the address does not change. It's like one time only.

Comment: @AnjelloJoshua: It is one an the same thing `Leave` and `LostFocus` in your case where as it is bit different when you look deeply inside. But in your case you can implement `Leave` event for your desired result. Hope it helps and I'll get the tick for Answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

Do Change as @Mohit suggested and also wrap the supplier name with single quotes, since supplier name is string type and in sql String should be wrap in single Quotes other wise this will give SQL Error

```
"SELECT address FROM tbl_Supplier WHERE supplier_name = '{0}'"
                                                    ----^
```